# How can I insert sequential numbers in an empty column in a SQL table.The numbers go from 1- 1,000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert numbers in a row in my SQL table that will populate the row from 1 to 1,000. The row is currently NULL.

I've been searching the internet, nothing found as of yet.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

ASN          ID
16111       NULL

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.  I also assume that you want the numbers in separate rows rather than in a single row.

Comment: Row already exist but empty??

Comment: @Eric Yes, the row currently states "NULL"

Comment: Is there a column to order the row by?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you want multiple rows, or a single row? You keep saying "a row", which is a single record, and that you want that single record to hold from 1 to 1000... which is just odd. Can you show examples of what you mean?

Comment: @pmbAustin It's a table in SQL. The columns are ASN (populated by designated numbers), LandNo. (NULL) <- This is the column I need to populate. It is currently NULL

Comment: Okay, so HOW do you want to populate it? That's not clear either. Does it matter which ASN row gets which number? You want exactly 1000 rows? All with the saem ASN number, or with whatever existing ASN number is there?  Can you please provide more information about what you have, and what you want? Can you show examples?

Comment: And I feel like you mean "Column" when you say "row" in your question, which is part of the reason... "I need to insert numbers in a column in my SQL table that will populate the column in each row from 1 to 1000. The column is currently NULL"

Comment: @pmbAustin Yes, I do mean column please disregard row. I am still learning SQL, so I am new to all the terminology and stuff. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @pmbAustin, the ASN column is fine, that is already populated. There are numbers in that row used for land identification purposes. The next row over, LandNo. is the row that is currently NULL. I need to populate it with numbers.

Comment: How do the numbers in the LandNo relate to teh numbers in the ASN column? Do you want to sort by ASN and then the lowest ASN value gets 1, and the highest gets up to 1000?

Comment: @pmbAustin This statement I used won't work because I need more than 1 values for (LandNo). INSERT INTO Import_Land (LandNo) VALUES (1)

Comment: @pmbAustin Yes! The ASN Value gets 1 and the highest goes to 1,000

Comment: Right, but you have to answer my other question first. WHICH of the many rows in there populated with many values of ASN do you want to get the 1? And which do you want to get the 2? And so on. Is it by order of ASN value? All the columns in the row are related to each other... the columns together make one row or record. I understand you want to populate the LandNo column for each row in your table, but the question you need to answer is HOW do you want to populate it? It's not independent of ASN. They're related.

Comment: No, there is no relation. Is there anyway I can send a screenshot?

Comment: @TechieGirlinCali The rows in a SQL data don't have a natural order. The order you see in your editor essentially means nothing. It's not even guaranteed to reflect the order that rows were created. So the question is whether you want to assign the numbering randomly or do it based on other data already there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, and this solution is probably way above your experience level, but it uses a Common Table Expression (CTE) to calculate a row number based on the order of ASN, and then joins to that ASN in order to UPDATE the existing NULL column with the row number.

This is just an example. It first creates a 'test' table and populates it with 5 rows, with NULL for the LanNo value. It then uses a SELECT to show you the contents of this test table.

It then uses the above strategy to update the NULL values to integers starting with 1.

Finally, it displays the contents of the table again to show the five rows have been updated with LandNo values according to the order of the ASN values.

```
-- Create a sample test table to use
CREATE TABLE Import_Land_test(ASN int, LandNo int NULL);

-- Create five rows of sample ASN data just for example
INSERT INTO Import_Land_test(ASN)
VALUES (123), (234), (345), (456), (567);

-- Show the test table
SELECT *
  FROM Import_Land_test;

-- Okay, now assign a LanNo value for each ASN, in order by ASN:
WITH SortedRowsAndRowNum AS (
    SELECT ASN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ASN) AS RowNumber
      FROM Import_Land_test
)
UPDATE ilt
   SET LandNo = RowNumber
  FROM Import_Land_test ilt
       INNER JOIN SortedRowsAndRowNum sr ON ilt.ASN = sr.ASN

-- Show the results
SELECT *
  FROM Import_Land_test;
```

Comment: Hey @TechieGirlinCali … did this answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[YourTable]
    SET [ID] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID]);
```

Comment: You can't use Windowed functions like that